# How to get bitmap of whole screen with Libgdx?

Tags: android, bitmap, libgdx

I would like to know how can I get bitmap of whole current screen. I would like to check RGBA values of selected pixel. My code that isn't working properly:

```
public class PixmapTest implements Screen
{
     //(...)

     private float getRedValue(int x, int y)
     {
          Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
          Color color = new Color();
          Color.rgba8888ToColor(color, pixmap.getPixel(x,y));
          pixmap.dispose();
          return color.r;
     }

     @Override
     public void render()
     {
          Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
          Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
          System.out.println(getRedValue(50, 50));
     }
}
```

It seems to me that the **getRedValue** method, should return **1.0**, but it returns **0.0**. I'm apologize for unproffesional question. I'm new to Libgdx and game development as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is you have created a blank pixmap that doesn't contain anything. Kumar Saurabh is right that you need to take the screen shot of that image and the function to get the pixel Value.

you can do it as

```
final Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(w, h, Format.RGBA8888);
ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
Color color = new Color();
Color.rgba8888ToColor(color, pixmap.getPixel(x,y));
pixmap.dispose();
return color.r;
```

Hope this might work for you

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the ScreenUtils package, e.g.

```
Image screenShot = new Image(ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferTexture());
```

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Screenshots

This is how stuff works

Do not  forget to get PNG.java class also as main logic is in it only

Also if u are using LibGdx 0.9.8 these classes are implicitly included in the gdx.jar